# Vuex state only updating after page refresh

Tags: axios, vuejs3, vuex

So I am new to Vue but I encountered a problem when following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uqpM7WVTKI4&t=2141s I copied her code exactly but I am getting a different behaviour. After the user submits the login form an API call is made and a bearer token is stored in the header. After that the user gets redirected to the home page where they are greeted with their name. The only problem is that after the user is redirected the hello message is not displaying because it thinks the user isn't logged in. But when a manual page refresh is done everything seems to be fine.

How can I make it so the user doesn't manually has to refresh the page?

Main.js

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import "./assets/css/reset.css"
import "./assets/css/style.css"


// Import SweetAlert2
import VueSweetalert2 from 'vue-sweetalert2';
import 'sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.min.css';

import router from './router'

import './axios.js'

// import { createStore } from 'vuex'
import store from './vuex';

// const app = createApp(App)

// app.use(router)
// app.use(VueSweetalert2)
// app.use(store)
// app.mount('#app')
createApp(App)
    .use(router)
    .use(VueSweetalert2)
    .use(store)
    .mount('#app')
```

router.js

```
import { createWebHistory, createRouter } from "vue-router";
import Home from "@/components/Home.vue";
import Login from "@/components/Login.vue";
import Register from "@/components/Register.vue";

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Home",
    component: Home,
  },
  {
    path: "/login",
    name: "Login",
    component: Login,
  },
  {
    path: "/register",
    name: "Register",
    component: Register,
  }
];

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes,
});

export default router;
```

Home.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1 v-if="user">Hello {{ user.name }}!</h1>
        <h1 v-if="!user">You are not logged in</h1>
    </div>  
</template>


<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';


    export default{
        name: 'Home',
        computed: {
            ...mapGetters(['user'])
        },
        
        
        
    }
</script>
```

Nav.vue

```
<template>
<nav>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="@/assets/logoipsum-250.png" alt="Logo">
        </div>

        <div class="links">
            <div class="not-logged-in" v-if="!user">
                <router-link class="button light-blue" to="/login">Login</router-link>
                <router-link class="" to="/register">Register</router-link>
            </div>
            <div class="logged-in" v-if="user">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" @click="handleLogout" class="button light-blue">Logout</a>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
</template>


<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';
    export default {
        name: 'Nav',
        
        methods: {
            handleLogout() {
                localStorage.removeItem('token');
                this.$store.dispatch('user', null);
                this.$router.push('/');
            }
        },
        computed: {
            ...mapGetters(['user'])
        }
    }
</script>
```

vuex.js

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex'


const state = {
    user: null
};

const store = createStore({
    state,
    getters: {
        user: (state) => {
            return state.user;
        }
    },
    actions: {
        user(context, user){
            context.commit('user', user);
        }
    },
    mutations:  {
        user(state, user){
            state.user = user;
        }
    }
})



export default store
```

Login.vue

```
<template>


    <div class="login-wrapper">
        <!-- .prevent is for preventing refresh on submit -->
        <form @submit.prevent="handleSubmit">
            <h1>Login</h1>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" v-model="email" placeholder="john@doe.com">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" v-model="password" placeholder="*****">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="button light-blue">Login</button>
        </form>
    </div>
  


</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default{
        name: 'Login',
        data() {
            return {
                email: '',
                password: '',
            }
        },
        methods: {
             async handleSubmit(){
                const response =  await axios.post('auth/login', {
                    email: this.email,
                    password: this.password

                });
                

                // Store API token
                localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token);

                // Store user in vuex   
                this.$store.commit('user', response.data.user);
               
                this.$router.push('/');

                


                // If logged in
                // if (response.status == '200'){
                // }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

App.vue

```
<template>
<Nav/>
<router-view/>
</template>

<script>
import Nav from './components/Nav.vue'
import axios from 'axios';



export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Nav,
  },
  async created(){
      const response = await axios.get('user');

      this.$store.commit('user', response.data)

  }
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution it's add a watch in your state, something like that in your Home.vue

```
watch: {
    user: {
      immediate: true,
      handler() {
        this.$forceUpdate();
      },
    },
  },
```